# The set of projection operators is manifold?

Tags: manifolds, projection

How  can I  prove that the set operators with rank $k$ is a manifold? More precisaly I would like prove that the set
$\{ P\in L(\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbb{R}^{m}): P^{2}=P\quad and \quad rank(P)=k\}$  is a manifold of class $C^{\infty}$ and dimension $k(m-k)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m^{2}}$. This is a question of Elon's lima book.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There's something wrong/misleading here. It doesn't make sense to talk about the composition $P^2$ unless $m = n$

Comment: You have reason, I am going to make a correction. Thank you.